# Is it possible to put a location marker on a google map without requesting it from the google server?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Really quick/simple question that will determine which map API i use for my project.

I dont need an example- ill figure that out, i just need to know if the capabilities are there.

If i have store geocode (latitude, longitude) coordinates in a database, can i put one of those little red markers on a google map without having to actually make a geocoding request from google?

Additional question:

Also, would it count towards any quotas every time i display one of their maps, even if i give them the geocoded coordinates? Because i mean technically their map still has to find those coordinates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Yes — you tell the API the coordinates of where to put the marker, rather than get Google to find those coordinates.

Q2: The usage limits are [published by Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits). You can have up to 25000 [map loads](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) per day. If you don't use the geocoder because you provide the coordinates yourself, then you don't use a geocoder access.